# mongodb query documents matching specific field using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how to query fields mongodb using matching name 
here is my nodejs query code

```
Session.model
    .find({}, { slug: 0 })
    .limit(Number(req.query.limit))
    .sort('createdAt')
    .populate({
      path: 'day stage tags speakers',
      select: 'name'
    })
```

`
Here is the data i get by the above query

```
    "session": [
    {
        "_id": "5e6d052c0a9c7d2d1f2981f6",
        "__v": 0,
        "day": {
            "_id": "5e6d051b0a9c7d2d1f2981f3",
            "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "description": "",
        "stage": {
            "_id": "5e6d05200a9c7d2d1f2981f4",
            "name": "Stage 1"
        },
        "Tracker": {
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:12.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:12.000Z"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "speakers": [],
        "endingTime": "2020-03-14T07:30:00.000Z",
        "startingTime": "2020-03-14T07:00:00.000Z",
        "name": "Session 2 Day 1 Stage 1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e6d05530a9c7d2d1f2981f7",
        "__v": 0,
        "day": {
            "_id": "5e6d051b0a9c7d2d1f2981f3",
            "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "description": "",
        "stage": {
            "_id": "5e6d05230a9c7d2d1f2981f5",
            "name": "Stage 2"
        },
        "Tracker": {
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:51.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:51.000Z"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "speakers": [],
        "endingTime": "2020-03-14T08:00:00.000Z",
        "startingTime": "2020-03-14T07:30:00.000Z",
        "name": "Session 2 Day 1 Stage 1"
    },
]
```

instead i want to get the data by day.name something like this or close to it
the idea is to get the data in the same day together

```
"session": [
"day": {
    "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z",
    [    {
        "_id": "5e6d052c0a9c7d2d1f2981f6",
        "__v": 0,
        "description": "",
        "stage": {
            "_id": "5e6d05200a9c7d2d1f2981f4",
            "name": "Stage 1"
        },
        "Tracker": {
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:12.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:12.000Z"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "speakers": [],
        "endingTime": "2020-03-14T07:30:00.000Z",
        "startingTime": "2020-03-14T07:00:00.000Z",
        "name": "Session 2 Day 1 Stage 1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e6d05530a9c7d2d1f2981f7",
        "__v": 0,
        "description": "",
        "stage": {
            "_id": "5e6d05230a9c7d2d1f2981f5",
            "name": "Stage 2"
        },
        "Tracker": {
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:51.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-14T16:24:51.000Z"
        },
        "tags": [],
        "speakers": [],
        "endingTime": "2020-03-14T08:00:00.000Z",
        "startingTime": "2020-03-14T07:30:00.000Z",
        "name": "Session 2 Day 1 Stage 1"
    }
]
```

}
]

i tried mapping them after retrieving the data from db but also with no luck

Comment: Hey there! please, let me see if I understood properly your question. You want to be able to access the data by using the ‘dot syntax’, e.g. day.name , instead of the whole dataset. Did I get your right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No i want to get all the data. for example i have the same day name like this `        "day": {
            "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z"
        },` multiple times in the database. i want to retrive all the documents that have the  `        "day": {
            "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z"
        },` in them

Comment: for example the above data contains the same day": { "name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z" } twice. so i want to combine the documents and retrive them

Comment: Can you add the schema definiton?

Comment: Hey there, can you try this `Session.find("day.name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z" )` ? it works for subdocuments, since you are using populate, I am not sure will work.

Comment: I would test it myself, but I would have to create a lot of code, unless you can send the code somehow,

Comment: hi here is the schema definition : https://pastebin.com/my0L04RY

Comment: sure here is the project source code : https://github.com/Ov3rControl/back-end-task.git

Comment: @JorgePires tried Session.find("day.name": "2020-03-13T22:00:00.000Z" ) didn't work

Comment: the output? what did you see?

Comment: is your dataset local? I mean, if you created in cloud, it would be easier to make tests. I have downloaded the code, thanks

Comment: @JorgePires here is the output https://pastebin.com/e7QcQkGn

Comment: Hey there, unfortunately I cannot help, you are using keystone for your schema, I am familiar to mongoose, it is similar, but not the same. I will pass! hopefully someone more experienced will show up!